# Element is undefined error in jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jspdf

I am trying to make an app in which the user can download a certain table as PDF. I am trying to use jsPDF for the purpose but due to some reasons or other , it is not working. The latest error which I am getting in the console is `TypeError: element is undefined` in the file `jspdf.plugin.from_html.js` .

Here is my approach:

I have the following headers:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script>
```

One thing that may be noted here is the fact that **My table is populated dynamically from values provided by my backend during the page load itself**

The table looks like:

```
<div id="huh">

<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="recent">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
            Spent On
            </th>
            <th>
            Amount
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead> 

</table>
    </div>
```

The table contains actual data when I invoke the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     function demoFromHTML() {
         var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'in', 'letter');
         var source = document.getElementById('huh');
         var specialElementHandlers = {
             '#bypassme': function(element, renderer) {
                 return true;
             }
         };

         doc.fromHTML(
            $('#testcase').get(0), // [Refer Exact code tutorial][2]HTML string or DOM elem ref.
             0.5,    // x coord
             0.5,    // y coord
             {
                 'width': 7.5, // max width of content on PDF
                 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
             });

         doc.output('dataurl');
    }

    </script>

<button onclick="javascript:demoFromHTML();">PDF</button>
```

I took some code from samples and examples. Any ideas where I am going wrong? 
Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Your `#testcase` is not defined

try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     function demoFromHTML() {
         var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'in', 'letter');
         //var source = document.getElementById('huh');
         var specialElementHandlers = {
             '#bypassme': function(element, renderer) {
                 return true;
             }
         };

         doc.fromHTML(
            $('#huh').get(0), // [Refer Exact code tutorial][2]HTML string or DOM elem ref.
             0.5,    // x coord
             0.5,    // y coord
             {
                 'width': 7.5, // max width of content on PDF
                 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
             });

         doc.output('dataurl');
    }

    </script>
```

Here is the working example http://jsfiddle.net/xzZ7n/898/